# java regex get just the filename

Tags: java, regex

need some help on pattern mathcing; I need to extract just the filename from a string like:

```
https://www.testsite.com/files/form/anonymous/api/library/ecb198be-1f05-4b0b-b0cd-7d878488a8c4/document/050cc508-1ea6-4b5f-a22b-b3edbdf6291f/media/x.jpg
```

just the x.jpg part

& also from this string:

```
<img alt="/JAGC/Images?action=AttachFile&amp;do=get&amp;target=Images/x.jpg">
```

& if they are the same image, then replace the target with the URL string.

I can regex out the the

any help please?

Comment: yeah; Pattern pathPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)");
but that just gives me the whole string again!

Comment: Please add it as a part of the question. It will help other to rectify mistakes in it (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
String filename1 = url.replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)", "$1");
String filename2 = xml.replaceAll(".*/([^\"]+)\".*", "$1");
if (filename1.equals(filename2))
    xml = xml.replaceAll("(.*/)([^\"]+)(\".*)", "$1" + url + "$3");
```

Comment: class; thanks; I nearly have it just have to get this instead:

<img alt="https://www.testsite.com/files/form/anonymous/api/library/ecb198be-1f05-4b0b-b0cd-7d878488a8c4/document/050cc508-1ea6-4b5f-a22b-b3edbdf6291f/media/x.jpg" src="https://www.testsite.com/files/form/anonymous/api/library/ecb198be-1f05-4b0b-b0cd-7d878488a8c4/document/050cc508-1ea6-4b5f-a22b-b3edbdf6291f/media/x.jpg" title="" width="600">

Comment: I can do it, but could you edit your question to show the complete initial XML and complete expected final XML after injecting the URL (when filename s match)?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't need any regexp.

Use like this:

```
String code = "...";
String filename = code.substring(code.lastIndexOf("/")+1, code.length());
```

Edit: 
And in the second case, you dont need the ending of the tag, so use code.length()-2

Comment: What about `<img ... />`?

Comment: And what about different file path separators?

Comment: @PeterRader Then use code.lastIndexOf("\"") instead of code.length()-2

Comment: @ferrerverck You can check the file separators, and use the actual in the lastIndexOf method.

Comment: thanks; the filename bit you gave is perfect; I have this now, nearly there:
    Pattern imgPattern = Pattern.compile("(<\\s*img\\s*alt\\s*=\\s*\").*?(\"\\s*>)");

so I have the correct x.jpg from the filname; how do I change the img alt bit?
    Matcher imgMatcher = imgPattern.matcher(replaceAllTags);
    while(imgMatcher.find()){
        System.err.println("match at "+imgMatcher.group());
 if( imgMatcher.group().contains(filename)) {
     System.err.println("YES");
 } else {
 System.err.println("NO");
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.replaceAll("^.*([a-z]+\\.[a-z]+).*$","$1");
```

The () group the filename to $1.